# How to distribute increasing numbers across range and ensure they sum to N?

Tags: python, numpy, statistics

Say N=150 and I have steps=100.

I want a function that will make 100 (or any number I choose) entries to an array, that are increasing at some rate I can set and they all sum to N. Ideally i would set a min and max.

```
Examples: min=1, max=4

distributed_array = [1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 ...  3.9, 4]

np.sum(distributed_array) = 150
```

Comment: You can't specify minimum, maximum, sum, and number of steps at the same time with even steps. There aren't enough degrees of freedom for that.

Comment: Minimum, maximum, and number of steps determine the sum.

Comment: The spacing doesn't need to be .1, it just needs to spaced from 1 to 4 and sum to N (150 in the example). The spacing should be somewhat consistent though.

Comment: The spacing would need to be highly inconsistent, considering that 100 numbers that sum to 150 must have an average of 1.5, which is much closer to 1 than 4. (Also, you haven't made it clear whether you want 100 steps or 100 entries.)

Comment: 100 entries in the array but that should be configurable. The difference between entries can vary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your statement over-constrains the problem such that it often won't have a valid answer.

If you want an arithmetic series containing `k` values which sum to `N` with a step size `r`, you get

```
sum(x, x + r, x + 2*r, ... x + (k - 1) * r)

  == k * (2 * x + (k - 1) * r) / 2       # by Gauss

  == N     # by the problem definition
```

which you can rearrange to find

```
min == x == N / k - (k - 1) * r / 2

max == x + (k - 1) * r == N / k + (k - 1) * r / 2
```

Looking at this, it should be clear that the median of any such series must be `N / k` - so, using your example of N = 150 and k = 100, the median must be 1.5 - so min = 1 and max = 4 is not possible.

Comment: This is right, you cannot easily choose a min and a max.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is an `arithmetic list` (math) meaning that we can calculate how many `steps` we have to take from `minValue` to `maxValue`, if we know the `sum` of the list and the min/max Values beforehand.

The equation for getting the `sum` of an `arithmetic list` is:

```
// The sum of the list
theSum = n*(minNum+maxNum)/2
```

We can now solve for `n` (the number of values we need to have including `minNum` and `maxNum`):

```
n = theSum*2/(minNum + maxNum)
```

**The program:**

```
theSum = 12.0
minNum = 1.0
maxNum = 5.0
n = int(theSum*2/(minNum + maxNum))

print(np.linspace(minNum, maxNum, num=n))
```

outputs:

```
[ 1.          2.33333333  3.66666667  5.        ]
```

and to confirm the sum:

```
print(sum(np.linspace(minNum, maxNum, num=n)))
```

outputs:

```
12.0
```

Comment: That doesn't ensure np.sum(array) = N

Comment: @Nish Ok. I edited my answer. Now you can specify the desired sum, min and max value.